# Can I control broken iPad from computer?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

My iPad's touch screen was broken about 1 year ago. I've dropped bottle on the screen and now the touch screen not working. I've sent it to service but the service hadn't repaired it, but the iPad is still working without touch.

Is it possible to control the iPad from my PC? if it's possible, I'd like to install an app called Duet Display to use my iPad as a second monitor.

Comment: Why didn't you just send it back to the place that failed to fix it?

Comment: because 1 year ago apple turkey didn't repair ipads. so i've sent it to third party service.

Comment: You've tagged your question [jailbreak], does that mean the device is *already* jailbroken?

Comment: no, it's not jabilbroken. maybe there is a solution with jailbrake applications.

Answer (score 1):

My iPad Mini has the similar broken screen, why not go to the third party service to change a new screen, which works well.

You can transfer files between iPad and computer, however it can't work as the second monitor.

Comment: actually via duedisplay application, i can use ipad as second monitor. i need install and run app from pc